# What does "I gotta go" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is "I gotta go" closer in meaning to "I have to go" or "I should go"? I mean, how strong is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, despite what Soverein Sun says,  "I gotta go" can mean both "I have to go" or "I should go."  There is little difference between the two statements, except that the latter is somewhat softer.

Comment: Please wait a day or two before accepting an answer, even if you receive a good one right away. For why this is usually wise, read [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Comment: *I gotta go = I **have** [got] to go = I **must** go*. Alternatively, *I oughta go = I ought to go = I **should** go*. Different words with potentially different implied meanings, but note that very often the speaker wouldn't want to be drawn on whether he's leaving because he ***must, ought to*** or simply ***wants*** to go.

Comment: @Robusto I would agree but could you explain this difference?

Comment: @SovereignSun: "I gotta <verb>" can express either necessity or desire. Not sure what you don't understand.

Comment: @Robusto **I gotta go** is either **I have to go** or **I have hot to go**, it can't mean **I should go**, although it can mean **I need to go**, I'm sure it can also mean **I must go**.

Comment: @SovereignSun: You're thinking at the atomic/literal level of grammar. Think instead about how the expression is actually used. As a parallel, think about the statement "Yeah, right." Two affirmative words,  put together, which can be used as a negative statement. Remember: "No language makes perfect sense."—John McWhorter

Comment: @Robusto You know, i can do that in my mother tongue since I feel how it works. it is rather difficult to do it in English since I'm only using it and not living it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**I gotta go**" means "**I have got to go**" *(more informal)* and "**I have to go**". Both mean the same.

**[Have (got) to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-to-and-have-to)** is used to refer to *obligations which come from outside the speaker*

- **have (got) to** is a requirement. *(I am forced to go)*
- **should** is a suggestion (optional). *(I want to go although I may stay)*

Comment: *(Have) got to VERB* is not restricted to deontic (obligation) uses: it can also be epistemic ("That's got to hurt").

Comment: @StoneyB It is only in Am.E?

Comment: No; epistemic *have got to* appears to be more widely used in AmE, but it is used and understood in BrE too.

Answer (score 5):

"I gotta go" is an abbreviated form of "I have got to go", so it is equivalent to "I have to go" or "I must go".

In US vernacular the *have* piece of *have got* is dropped as often as not, (but less often with the third-person singular *has got*) in both the possessive ("I got plenty of nothin") and 'modal' ("I got to go now", "That's got to hurt") senses. *Got* has in effect become an independent verb. In the US this *got* is still defective, used only as a 'simple present', but in some speech communities it is employed as an infinitive and takes *do* support:

> I'll pay you tomorrow, I don't got the cash now.
>   Don't you got a Prius? How do you like it?
>   Do you got five bucks you can lend me?

The first two were already common in General Southern when I was a boy sixty years ago; I believe the third is currently heard only in AAVE, but I imagine other dialects will pick it up in the next generation or so.